# Computing the derivative of a function defined by critical points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f_\lambda:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a set of continuous functions which depend continuously on $\lambda\in[c,d]\subset \mathbb{R}$ (by that I mean that I can see it as function $f(\lambda,x)$ over $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ continuous in $\lambda$ and $x$).

Suppose each $f_\lambda$ admits a unique critical point over $[a,b]$, then I can define the function

$F:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\mapsto f_\lambda(x_\lambda)$ , $x_\lambda$ critical point of $f_\lambda$.

My question is: given $\lambda_0\in[c,d]$, what is $\frac{d}{d\lambda}F|_{\lambda=\lambda_0}$?

Computing the limit I get

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(\lambda_0+h)-F(\lambda_0)}{h}&=&\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_{\lambda_0+h}(x_{\lambda_0+h})-f_{\lambda_0}(x_{\lambda_0})}{h}\\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\lambda_0+h,x_{\lambda_0+h})-f(\lambda_0,x_{\lambda_0})}{h}
\end{array}$$

But then I don't know how to proceed because $x_{\lambda_0+h}$ obviously depends on $h$.. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is far from obvious (and probably not true), that $x_\lambda $ is differentiable. Some rather unpleasant assumptions will allow you to calculate what you want though. First assume $F$ is 'sufficiently differentiable' -- you can make this more precise by counting derivatives in what follows. I'll use $y$ in place of your $\lambda$ to save typing, and $F(x,y)$ will be your $f(x,\lambda)$. Then let

$$G(x, y): = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x, y)$$

By assumption, for each $y$ there is a unique $x= x(y)$ such that $G(x(y), y)= 0$

Now assume in addition, that $x(y)$ is not a boundary point of $[a,b]$. You then know that $h(y) = G(x(y), y)$ is constant hence has zero $y$-derivative (if it were differentiable).
So, by formally taking the derivative,
$$0=\frac{d}{dy}h(y)= G_x(x(y), y) \frac{dx}{dy} + G_y(x(y), y).$$

From this you can solve for $\frac{dx}{dy}$ iff $ G_x(x(y), y)\neq 0$. With this information you can compute the derivative you asked for using the chain rule.